# How to use window focus messages for a Delphi on-screen keyboard form

Tags: forms, delphi, keyboard, focus

I need a built-in on screen numeric keypad in my Application. For various reasons I cannot use the [TMS Software](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/atkbd.asp) or other commercial component offerings. I'm very happy with a button-based solution shown below but I cannot yet see how to solve the focus switch issue where clicking the button activates the keypad form and I lose the focused control into which I wanted the characters. My solution works if I keep the keypad buttons within the target form but I would like a form-independent solution. Is there a way of disabling the button activation or knowing where the focus came from so that I can use something like Scree.ActiveControl :=?? to put it back?

[image]

Comment: For getting handle to the window that has keyboard focus try to use [GetFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646294%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but how to create unfocusable window I can't tell you now but you can get inspiration e.g. from TRxCalcEdit, it has such kind of a popup numpad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to create window with the frame which is unfocusable when you click it, so the following one is without border. And as Andreas mentioned, use TSpeedButtons.

```
type
  TKeypadForm = class(TForm)
    SpeedButton1: TSpeedButton;
    procedure SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
    procedure WMMouseActivate(var Message: TWMMouseActivate); message WM_MOUSEACTIVATE;
  end;

procedure TKeypadForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  Params.Style := WS_POPUP or WS_THICKFRAME;
end;

procedure TKeypadForm.WMMouseActivate(var Message: TWMMouseActivate);
begin
  Message.Result := MA_NOACTIVATE;
end;

procedure TKeypadForm.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(GetFocus, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_NUMPAD1, MakeLong(0, MapVirtualKey(VK_NUMPAD1, 0)));
end;
```

And here's how to show the keypad window

```
procedure TForm18.Edit1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  case Key of
    VK_RETURN: ShowWindow(KeypadForm.Handle, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
    VK_ESCAPE: ShowWindow(KeypadForm.Handle, SW_HIDE);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: And IMHO it's impossible to create framed window whose frame click doesn't focus the window, it would be quite confusing from the users point of view.

Comment: Thanks, you were right - the mouse message was vital, CreateParams not so. Brian.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a TSpeedButton for this task on your Keypad. TSpeedButton does not steel the Focus. But the Form does. And this is ugly, even if you give the focus back to your main form, the focus flickers between the two forms. So I would try to create a form without focus.

A flag named WS_EX_NOACTIVATE can be used to create a window (form) that does not become the foreground window when the user clicks it. Also, the system does not bring this window to the foreground when the user minimizes or closes the foreground window.

To create a non activatable form, override the CreateParams method as:

```
procedure TMainForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams) ;
 //const WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = $8000000;
 begin
   inherited;
   Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle + WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
 end;
```

When Delphi creates a form, the Create method calls the CreateWindowEx API function to create the actual window.

Before executing the CreateWindowEx, the CreateParams method is called - CreateParams allows you to change the default style of a window when it is created to suit your particular needs.

Comment: Still you can focus window. Even if you will include WM_MOUSEACTIVATE handling your buttons will get the focus.

Comment: Thanks, but CreateParams appears to do nothing for me. I font know why. But see my own answer below. Brian.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution is as follows. This creates a numeric pad with a border and - yes- it does activate if the border is clicked or resized, but clicking the buttons does not steal focus from the target form / control. Simply using CreateParams did not work for me - it seemed to need the WMMouseActivate message instead.

I've combined it with a routine that I found that posts the key to the OS, not just the focused control. Note that code below assumes some simple support from an ancestor form for setting a default size and position. Thanks for all your help.

```
unit UArtScreenKeyboardForm;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  UArtBaseForm, Buttons,
  StdCtrls;

type
  TArtScreenKeyboardForm = class(TArtBaseForm)
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure WMMouseActivate(var Message: TWMMouseActivate); message WM_MOUSEACTIVATE;
    procedure FormResize(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure DoOnbuttonClick(ASender: TObject);
    procedure DrawButtons;
  protected
    procedure SetDefaultSizeAndPosition; override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;



procedure ArtScreenKeyboardForm_Show;
procedure ArtScreenKeyboardForm_Hide;


implementation

{$R *.DFM}

uses
  UArtLibrary;

type
  TButtonKind = (
    bk0,
    bk1,
    bk2,
    bk3,
    bk4,
    bk5,
    bk6,
    bk7,
    bk8,
    bk9,
    bkPlus,
    bkMinus,
    bkDel,
    bkDiv,
    bkMul,
    bkEquals,
    bkDecPt,
    bkEnter );

const
  ButtonCaptions : array[TButtonKind] of string = (
    '0',
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4',
    '5',
    '6',
    '7',
    '8',
    '9',
    '+',
    '-',
    'Back',
    '/',
    '*',
    '=',
    '.',
    'Enter' );

  ScanCodes : array[TButtonKind] of cardinal = (
    Ord( '0' ),
    Ord( '1' ),
    Ord( '2' ),
    Ord( '3' ),
    Ord( '4' ),
    Ord( '5' ),
    Ord( '6' ),
    Ord( '7' ),
    Ord( '8' ),
    Ord( '9' ),
    VK_ADD,
    VK_SUBTRACT,
    8, {BACKSPACE}
    VK_DIVIDE,
    VK_MULTIPLY,
    Ord( '=' ),
    Ord( '.' ),
    VK_RETURN );


var
  ArtScreenKeyboardForm: TArtScreenKeyboardForm = nil;


procedure PostKeyEx32(key: Word; const shift: TShiftState; specialkey: Boolean) ;
 {
Parameters :
* key : virtual keycode of the key to send. For printable keys this is simply the ANSI code (Ord(character)) .
* shift : state of the modifier keys. This is a set, so you can set several of these keys (shift, control, alt, mouse buttons) in tandem. The TShiftState type is declared in the Classes Unit.
* specialkey: normally this should be False. Set it to True to specify a key on the numeric keypad, for example.

Description:
Uses keybd_event to manufacture a series of key events matching the passed parameters. The events go to the control with focus. Note that for characters key is always the upper-case version of the character. Sending without any modifier keys will result in a lower-case character, sending it with [ ssShift ] will result in an upper-case character!
}
type
  TShiftKeyInfo = record
    shift: Byte ;
    vkey: Byte ;
  end;

  ByteSet = set of 0..7 ;

const
  shiftkeys: array [1..3] of TShiftKeyInfo =
    ((shift: Ord(ssCtrl) ; vkey: VK_CONTROL),
    (shift: Ord(ssShift) ; vkey: VK_SHIFT),
    (shift: Ord(ssAlt) ; vkey: VK_MENU)) ;
var
  flag: DWORD;
  bShift: ByteSet absolute shift;
  j: Integer;
begin
  for j := 1 to 3 do
  begin
    if shiftkeys[j].shift in bShift then
      keybd_event(shiftkeys[j].vkey, MapVirtualKey(shiftkeys[j].vkey, 0), 0, 0) ;
  end;
  if specialkey then
    flag := KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY
  else
    flag := 0;

 keybd_event(key, MapvirtualKey(key, 0), flag, 0) ;
  flag := flag or KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
  keybd_event(key, MapvirtualKey(key, 0), flag, 0) ;

 for j := 3 downto 1 do
  begin
    if shiftkeys[j].shift in bShift then
      keybd_event(shiftkeys[j].vkey, MapVirtualKey(shiftkeys[j].vkey, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0) ;
  end;
end;




procedure TArtScreenKeyboardForm.DoOnbuttonClick(ASender: TObject);
var
  Btn : TSpeedButton;
  Kind : TButtonKind;
begin
  Btn := ASender as TSpeedButton;
  Kind := TButtonKind(StrToIntDef( Copy( Btn.Name, 4, MaxStrLen ), 0 ));
  PostKeyEx32( ScanCodes[Kind], [], False );

  // As suggested also:
  //PostMessage(GetFocus, WM_KEYDOWN, Ord('A'), 0 );
  // PostMessage(GetFocus, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_NUMPAD1, MakeLong(0, MapVirtualKey(VK_NUMPAD1, 0)));



end;



procedure TArtScreenKeyboardForm.WMMouseActivate(var Message: TWMMouseActivate);
begin
  Message.Result := MA_NOACTIVATE;
end;

procedure ArtScreenKeyboardForm_Show;
begin
  If ArtScreenKeyboardForm = nil then
    begin
    ArtScreenKeyboardForm := TArtScreenKeyboardForm.Create( Application );
    ArtScreenKeyboardForm.Show;
    end;

 Application.ProcessMessages;
end;





procedure ArtScreenKeyboardForm_Hide;
begin
 If ArtScreenKeyboardForm <> nil then
   begin
   ArtScreenKeyboardForm.Free;
   ArtScreenKeyboardForm := nil;
   end;
end;


procedure TArtScreenKeyboardForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DrawButtons;
end;

procedure TArtScreenKeyboardForm.SetDefaultSizeAndPosition;
begin
  inherited;
  Width := 300;
  PlaceControl( Self, cpWorkAreaTopLeft );
end;

procedure TArtScreenKeyboardForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject;
  var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
  ArtScreenKeyboardForm := nil;
end;


procedure TArtScreenKeyboardForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Constraints.MinWidth  := 200;
  Constraints.MinHeight := (120 * 5)  div 4;
end;


procedure TArtScreenKeyboardForm.DrawButtons;

  procedure AddButton( ATop, ALeft, AWidth, AHeight : integer; AKind : TButtonKind );

    function WidthPix( AValue : integer ) : integer;
    begin
      Result := AValue * (ClientWidth div 4);
    end;

    function HeightPix( AValue : integer ) : integer;
    begin
      Result := AValue * (ClientHeight div 5);
    end;

  var
    Button : TSpeedButton;
  begin
    Button := TSpeedButton.Create( Self );
    Button.Parent := Self;

    Button.Left := WidthPix( ALeft );
    Button.Top  := HeightPix( ATop );
    Button.Width := WidthPix( AWidth );
    Button.Height := HeightPix( AHeight );
    Button.Visible := True;

    Button.Name := Format( 'btn%d', [Ord( AKind )] );
    Button.Caption := ButtonCaptions[ AKind ];

    button.OnClick := DoOnbuttonClick;
  end;



var
  I : integer;
begin
  Height := (Width * 5) div 4;

  ApplyScreenIconTitleFontToFont( Font );

  Font.Size := Font.Size + ((Height-250) div 30);

  Font.Style := Font.Style + [fsBold];
  Font.Color := clGray;

  For I := ComponentCount-1 downto 0 do
    If Components[I] is TSpeedButton then
      Components[I].Free;

  Addbutton( 0, 0, 1, 1, bkDel      );
  Addbutton( 0, 1, 1, 1, bkEquals   );
  Addbutton( 0, 2, 1, 1, bkDiv      );
  Addbutton( 0, 3, 1, 1, bkMul      );

  Addbutton( 1, 0, 1, 1, bk7        );
  Addbutton( 1, 1, 1, 1, bk8        );
  Addbutton( 1, 2, 1, 1, bk9        );
  Addbutton( 1, 3, 1, 1, bkMinus    );

  Addbutton( 2, 0, 1, 1, bk4        );
  Addbutton( 2, 1, 1, 1, bk5        );
  Addbutton( 2, 2, 1, 1, bk6        );
  Addbutton( 2, 3, 1, 1, bkPlus     );

  Addbutton( 3, 0, 1, 1, bk1        );
  Addbutton( 3, 1, 1, 1, bk2        );
  Addbutton( 3, 2, 1, 1, bk3        );
  Addbutton( 3, 3, 1, 2, bkEnter    );

  Addbutton( 4, 0, 2, 1, bk0        );
  Addbutton( 4, 2, 1, 1, bkDecPt    );
end;

procedure TArtScreenKeyboardForm.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DrawButtons;
end;

initialization
finalization
  FreeAndNil( ArtScreenKeyboardForm );
end.
```